# R, SQL, and existing objects not existing

Tags: sql, r, teradata, r-dbi

```
DBI::dbListFields(con, "ibin_acq")
#>  [1] "MANDT"           "IN_RECNO"        "VALFR"           "VALTO"          
#>  [5] "AENNR"           "DELFLAG"         "IN_STANCE"       "MLANG"          
#>  [9] "SORTF"           "OBJNR"           "IBASE"           "AMOUNT"         
#> [13] "UNIT"            "DATUV"           "TECHS"           "IN_OBJNR"       
#> [17] "IN_GUID"         "OBJECTTYP"       "VOID"            "CSTATUS"        
#> [21] "CUCOCNT"         "EXPERT"          "MAT_VARIANT"     "ATAUT"          
#> [25] "KLART"           "CRNAM"           "CRTIM"           "UPNAM"          
#> [29] "UPTIM"           "SOURCE_ID"       "EXTRACTION_DATE"
```

My R command above utlizing the DBI package works fine (querying a Teradata SQL table). When I try and look at the first ten rows of this table I get the following error:

```
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select top 10 * from ibin_acq")
#> Error in new_result(connection@ptr, statement) : 
#>   nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1344: 42S02: [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver]
#> [Teradata Database](-3807)Object 'ibin_acq' does not exist.
```

The error states that the `ibin_acq` object does not exist, yet my first code chunk (above) proves this object does exist. No?

```
DBI::dbReadTable(con, "ibin_acq")
#> Error in new_result(connection@ptr, statement) : 
#>   nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1344: 42S02: [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver]
#> [Teradata Database](-3807)Object 'ibin_acq' does not exist.
```

This code chunk above does not work either. Why can I `dbListFields(con, "ibin_acq")` yet I can't `dbReadTable(con, "ibin_acq")`?

---

Edit for @Fred - here's that command and the output:

```
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT CURRENT_USER, DATABASE, DatabaseName, 
                TableName FROM DBC.TablesV WHERE TableName='ibin_acq'")
#>   Current_User         Database    DataBaseName TableName
#> 1      6841794 P0_IM_DL_QCM02_V P0_IM_ACQ_GCS_T  IBIN_ACQ
#> 2      6841794 P0_IM_DL_QCM02_V        DBA_DATA  ibin_acq
#> 3      6841794 P0_IM_DL_QCM02_V P0_IM_ACQ_GCS_V  IBIN_ACQ
```

Comment: It looks like there's issues with Teradata and that package (https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/55). I'd try using the more verbose syntax as shown in section 4.2 here and see if it works... https://downloads.teradata.com/blog/odbcteam/2016/02/r-with-teradata-odbc

Comment: might be default schema/database specification issue? where does the table exist?

Comment: Without knowing what's going on behind the curtain with thedbListFields method, it's hard to be sure.  Try qualifying your select with the database name.

Comment: To answer the comments: @cory `DBI::dbGetQuery(con, paste('select top 10 * from "ibin_acq"'))` unfortunately did not work. @EJJ The table exists from the `con` connection I've already made to Teradata. @Andrew I'm not quite sure how to qualify my select with a database name, how do I do that?

Comment: `select top 10 * from <database name>.ibin_acq`.

Comment: @Andrew unfortunately  qualifying the select with the database name did not work, and yields the same "object does not exist error".

Comment: Don't know if using [Teradata SQL Driver for R](https://github.com/Teradata/r-driver) instead of ODBC connection would make a difference. Are you able to find the table in the results of `dbListTables` or `SELECT databasename, tablename FROM DBC.TablesV WHERE tablename='ibin_acq'`

Comment: @Fred yes `dbListTables` does indeed show the `ibin_acq` table. It looks like you're a Teradata employee. Is there a way to contact you direct? My company does have a Teradata support contract should it matter.

Comment: Try this query: `SELECT CURRENT_USER, DATABASE, DatabaseName, TableName FROM DBC.TablesV WHERE TableName='ibin_acq'`. Does the returned value for DatabaseName match that returned for DATABASE? Do either of them match CURRENT_USER?

Comment: Just a shot-in-the-dark, maybe the package is suppressing double quoted objects.  What if you try putting double quotes around `bin_acq`?

Comment: @Fred I tried your latest query unsuccessfully but I may be doing something wrong. I'm populating the DATABASE as `P0_IM_DL_QCM02_V` and the DatabaseName (DBCName) as `00.11.22.3333`, the actual IP being different. Hidden for privacy reasons. I don't really know how to match them to CURRENT_USER. I'm not exactly sure what that even means. @ravioli The double quotes didn't work either :(

Comment: What error do you get from this query? `DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT CURRENT_USER, DATABASE, DatabaseName, TableName FROM DBC.TablesV WHERE TableName='ibin_acq'")` Or does it just return no data?

Comment: @Fred not sure if I got syntax right but here is the command`dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT 6841794, P0_IM_DL_QCM02_V, 18.44.74.174, ibin_acq FROM P0_IM_DL_QCM02_V.ibin_acq WHERE TableName='ibin_acq'")` and here's the output: `Error in new_result(connection@ptr, statement) : nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1344: 42000: [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database](-3707)Syntax error, expected something like a name or a Unicode delimited identifier between a decimal number and the number '.74'.`

Comment: My query doesn't have any "variables" for you to substitute values. It's literally the exact text I wanted you to run.

Comment: @Fred just appended the original question with that exact command and it's output. Please see and let me know your thoughts.

Comment: It looks like the Teradata SQL Engine is using **P0_IM_DL_QCM02_V** as the  default qualifier but it likely needs to be **P0_IM_ACQ_GCS_V** for this database object. (I presume dbListFields is doing some sort of search like my query, where the schema / DatabaseName qualifier is ignored.) Try specifying the latter value for `schema` in your dbGetQuery or dbReadTable.

Comment: @Fred That worked. If I establish the connection with the `P0_IM_ACQ_GCS_V` DataBaseName instead of the `P0_IM_DL_QCM02_V` Database everything works as intended. Both the `dbListFields(con, "ibin_acq")` and `dbReadTable(con, "ibin_acq")` commands function properly. How do I know whether to use the "Database" or the "DataBaseName" when I run these queries? Do you mind writing up an answer and I can mark this question solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "DATABASE" **P0_IM_DL_QCM02_V** returned by the metadata query against DBC.TablesV is the session default qualifier (schema). But the view you intended to access appears to be in **P0_IM_ACQ_GCS_V** DatabaseName.

Either change the default "DATABASE" setting for the connection or explicitly specify a schema for the query.

Comment: It appears that dbListFields does not apply the default schema, though dbGetQuery and dbReadTable both do.

Answer (score 0):

Thats surely an `access` issue. Give access to those objects you want by something similar to `Grant` n then use it.

Comment: Does that mean I don't have permission to view that object? I'm not sure I understand. Can you expand on your answer a little bit? Thank you.

Comment: Unless R is wrapping Teradata errors inside it's own messages, this is not an access issue.  Teradata will return something like `the user does not have select access to <object>`.